# Formsubmit.io "_next " tag not redirecting even with fully qualified url path

Tags: form-submit

Team working with formsubmit.io in capture form submissions and send an email. However, when leveraging the _next tag as described on the documentation, the form does not redirect to a success page that was created in html. Anyone else experiencing this issue? Any order of precedence for this field in the form? Below is my code if it helps. Appreciate any feedback you might be able to provide.

" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                
                  
                    Name
                    
                    
                  
                  
                    Email
                    
                    
                  
                  
                    Message

Implemented the input tag as specified on the documentation for _next feature
I tried changing the order of hidden input fields
I validated the full qualified url does render the success page when linked to directly
tried code with input fields as self closing tags and without
I was expecting the form, once submitted, to redirect to my success.html page instead, the screen is presenting a formsubmit page that does not provide the desired user desired.

The data on the form submits successfully, it is just that the redirect after posting is not executed as expected.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  The _next tag seems to have been replaced with a _redirect tag.  The documentation should be updated on their site.  Here is the example:                            
       <input name="_redirect" type="hidden" id="name" value="https://your website url">